# tweepy.Cursor returns unrelated search results to the query I selected

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

As part of my Master's Degree, I need to collect data from Twitter for future machine learning models.

## What's the problem?

I am trying to get tweets with a given hashtag (#), something really simple such as **#climatechange**, so as I understood from other questions at stack overflow, I need to add **q** parameter and pass the "#climatechange" string there.

Here is the code:

```
# Loads JSON Credentials.
twitter_credentials_json = load_twitter_credentials('TwitterCredentials.json')

# Creates tweepy.API object.
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials_json['consumer_key'], twitter_credentials_json['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials_json['access_token'], twitter_credentials_json['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

data_list = []

# Iterates through the required tweets and adds them to the list.
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#climatechange", since="2020-01-01", until="2020-10-01").items(100):
  data_list.append(tweet._json)
# Drops everything to the file system.
with open(f"Tweets {get_datetime_as_string()}.json", 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
  outfile.write(json.dumps(data_list))
  outfile.close()
```

As you can see I am searching at Twitter, I require every text that contains the string "#climatechange", since 2020-01-01, until 2020-10-01, and I take 100 items.
Now I open the JSON file and I see some unrelated tweets in the JSON file, **that doesn't contain "#climatechange" text**. I decided to check at the whole object that I received from tweepy and there is also no mention for "#climatechange" string anywhere.

For example:

> "text": "RT @BetteMidler: The #GOP cannot govern.  Remember they
> presided over #9-11, the #IraqWar, the 2008 #GreatRecession, &
> when they returned t\u2026"

> "text": "RT @DeWayne_Fulton: #Texas can lead the way in energy
> innovation--safe, clean, efficient, renewable
> energy.\n\n@Lizzie4Congress knows that th\u2026",

To summarize it until now:

1. I get tweets from twitter by specific conditions.
2. I save them to the file system.
3. I open the JSON file and about 10% of the tweets **don't have the "#climatechange" string in them**.

---

## What I tried to solve this issue?

1. Of course, the first thing I tried to do is going to tweepy official documentation for the Cursor object but I didn't find anything useful there, I didn't even find the q parameter or anything else, although many stack overflow solutions use those parameters.
   http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.9.0/cursor_tutorial.html
   It seems like the documentation isn't fully written or missing a lot of stuff, where did I go wrong with the documentation?
2. I searched at Stack Overflow and some more sites if someone had this issue too, but I didn't find anything relevant.
3. I searched for tweepy.Cursor solutions at StackOverflow to adjust my parameters and I tried adding someone parameters, removing some but still, nothing.
4. I tried going to tweepy.Cursor GitHub code to understand how it works but I didn't fully understand how it works so no success there.

---

As I understand once I specify the "q" parameter with some string it will search for strings that contain this query parameter and return only the valid tweets, but as I see it there is some problem and it returns unrelated tweets.

I will be happy to get some help or maybe if you can tell me what I miss, I am sure it's something small that I miss and that's the reason I don't get the right data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s very likely that the Tweets that seem unrelated are truncated to 140 characters and the text you’ve searched for is in the “extended” Tweet section. If you add `tweet_mode=extended` to the `api.search` call then it should retrieve the full Tweet text in the `full_text` field for the extended Tweets.

You should also be aware that the legacy standard Twitter search API (this is what `api.search` is calling) only supports searching back within the past 7 days of Tweets. For a longer period of time you will need to use the Twitter premium 30-day or full-archive search APIs.

Comment: [Andy Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262478/andy-piper) Thank you so much, adding tweet_mode='extended' solved the issue and it returns the full text.
So you're saying using Twitter API or using tweepy library that accesses Twitter API will return only 7 days of tweets from the current data? I must purchase the premium package of Twitter in order to get more than 7 days of tweets? Is there an API that receives more than 7 days of tweets? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the legacy standard search returns up to 7 days of data. There is a free tier (called "sandbox") available for both the 30-day and full-archive search APIs, but this is limited in the number of requests available. However, it may help you to achieve more like what you want. Also note that the premium API, as well as the new v2 API, do not have a concept of "extended" Tweets, as all Tweets contain full text by default.